# ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred en CentOS 7

Tags: oracle, centos

Estoy configurando un servidor en CentOS 7 para conectar con una base de datos Oracle dentro de la misma red.
IP ORACLE = 192.167.10.100
IP SERVER= 192.167.15.123

He instalado el Instant Client Package: Basic,SDK y SQL*Plus. [Link Descarga](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html).

Posteriormente establecer las variables de entorno:

ORACLE_HOME=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64

PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin

LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib

TNS_ADMIN=$ORACLE_HOME/network/admin

Al ingresar con el SQL * Plus mediante la cadena de conexión implícita:
Con el formato.

> sqlplus username/password@host:port/sid

```
sqlplus testuser/orcltiger@192.167.10.100:1521/testdb
```

Obtengo el error:
**ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred**

He podido conectar me con las mismas credenciales desde un PC Windows con Oracle SQL Developer pero desde CentOS obtengo error:

Alguien que me ayude a dar con la solución, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

Este enlace te explica el problema y las posibles causas. También donde se encuentra el archivo hosts para verificar si tienes una entrada DNS.

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_12170_tns_connect_timeout.htm

En el enlace se comenta que el error ORA-12170 se puede deber a distintas causas (firewall, base de datos o listener caído, parámetro sqlnet.ora incorrecto, problemas de red...).

La documentación comenta las causas y posibles soluciones al el error ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred:

> Cause: The server shut down because connection establishment or
>   communication with a client failed to complete within the allotted
>   time interval. This may be a result of network or system delays; or
>   this may indicate that a malicious client is trying to cause a Denial
>   of Service attack on the server.
>
> Action: If the error occurred because of a slow network or system,
>   reconfigure one or all of the parameters
>   SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, SQLNET.SEND_TIMEOUT,
>   SQLNET.RECV_TIMEOUT in sqlnet.ora to larger values. If a malicious
>   client is suspected, use the address in sqlnet.log to identify the
>   source and restrict access. Note that logged addresses may not be
>   reliable as they can be forged (e.g. in TCP/IP).
>
> Your sqlnet.ora file can be found in your $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
>   directory.

Sobre el error ORA-12170 y el archivo hosts:

> ORA-12170 and hosts file
>
> Verify that your /etc/hosts file has a DNS entry:
>
> 190.1.1.20  diogenes
>
> In Windows XP, make your hosts file is located at
>   win/system32/driver/etc/ and on UNIX, Linux, check /etc/hosts.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Acabo de editar mi comentario

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que no haya firewalls entre ambas redes, y si los hay, que este el puerto 1521 accesible a la subred 10.X hacia la subred 15.X.

Saludos.
Adrian